# pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure

Tags: debian, openldap

I have openldap and server Debian 8. I want to set ldap authentication. I have installed ldap-utils libnss-ldapd libpam-ldapd and set these.

```
# getent passwd user.name
user.name:x:1537:3174:User Name:/home/user.name:/bin/bash
# getent shadow user.name
user.name:*:15140:0:99999:7:::0
```

When I login I have this error:

> Sep 19 17:49:49 LDAPClient login[475]: pam_unix(login:auth): authentication failure; logname=LOGIN uid=0 euid=0 tty=/dev/tty1 ruser= rhost=  user=name.user
> Sep 19 17:49:49 LDAPClient login[475]: pam_ldap(login:auth): Authentication failure; user=name.user
> Sep 19 17:49:53 LDAPClient login[475]: FAILED LOGIN (1) on '/dev/tty1' FOR 'name.user', Authentication failure

I also set ssh, but have the same error:

> Sep 19 17:46:37 LDAPClient sshd[807]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=192.168.60.92  user=name.user
> Sep 19 17:46:37 LDAPClient sshd[807]: pam_ldap(sshd:auth): Authentication failure; user=name.user
> Sep 19 17:46:39 LDAPClient sshd[807]: Failed password for name.user from 192.168.60.92 port 63122 ssh2
> Sep 19 17:46:43 LDAPClient sshd[807]: pam_ldap(sshd:auth): Authentication failure; user=name.user
> Sep 19 17:46:45 LDAPClient sshd[807]: Failed password for name.user from 192.168.60.92 port 63122 ssh2

How to fix it? I don't have idea:

```
# /etc/nsswitch.conf
#
# Example configuration of GNU Name Service Switch functionality.
# If you have the `glibc-doc-reference' and `info' packages installed, try:
# `info libc "Name Service Switch"' for information about this file.

passwd:         compat ldap
group:          compat ldap
shadow:         compat ldap
gshadow:        files

hosts:          files dns
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files
```

the problem was in acl:

```
olcAccess: {2}to dn.subtree="ou=People,dc=example,dc=com"
  by peername.ip="192.168.250.78" read
  by peername.ip="xx.xx.xx.xx" read
  by peername.ip="192.168.250.204" read
  by dn="cn=replica,dc=example,dc=com" read
  by group.exact="cn=Directory Administrators,dc=example,dc=com" manage
  by dn.subtree="ou=Special Users,dc=example,dc=com" read
  by dn.subtree="ou=Special Users,dc=example,dc=com" read
  !!!by * none

olcAccess: {5}to *
  by peername.ip="xx.xx.xx.xx" read
  by peername.ip="192.168.250.204" read
  by group.exact="cn=Directory Administrators,dc=example,dc=com" manage
  by dn="cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com" write
  by dn="cn=replica,dc=example,dc=com" read
  by dn.subtree="ou=Special Users,dc=example,dc=com" read
  !!!by * none
```

Comment: Have you changed /etc/nsswitch.conf to point to LDAP?

Comment: yep, my  /etc/nsswitch.conf: `passwd:         combat ldap
group:          compat ldap
shadow:         compat ldap
gshadow:        files

hosts:          files dns
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files`

Comment: What does the command `getent passwd` output on the system? It should list all users, local and LDAP

Comment: @timFletcher yep, this command list all users, local and LDAP

Comment: The formating in the comment box makes it hard to read your nsswitch.conf contents, could you add them to the question. Also I think you are missing ldap on the shadow: line hence users but not passwd hashes.

Comment: @TimFletcher i add conf in the question

Comment: Looking at again it seems that `genent shadow` isn't really recommended any more. When I setup LDAP on Debian I used this document form the Debian wiki: https://wiki.debian.org/LDAP/NSS

Comment: @TimFletcher, thanks for help, i decided trouble. the problems was ACL LDAP

Comment: Could you update the question with this answer to help others, thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you check your shadow you have not set a password for you account.
`user.name:*:15140:0:99999:7:::0` ---- `*` means no password.

The system does not allow no password login.

TRY to create a password for your account and retry to login

Comment: but i have pass.